# design pattern for scheduled tasks

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks

I've got a much of tasks I need to perform on a scheduled basis.  For example I might need to query an ftp site every 30 minutes, and look for files in a directory every 2 minutes.

I'm looking for a reference design pattern or potentially even a library that manage multiple tasks that each execute on a scheduled basis.

Comment: Why not use _Windows Task Scheduler_ from c#?  (love your crazy avatar pic by the way ;) )

Comment: I have recently come across Hangfire (http://hangfire.io/), and I must say, it is awesome.